# Comparing two lists of tuples using IN keyword

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two lists of tuples both of the format `(integer, string)`.

The first list is a subset of the second list and I only want elements of the second list that share an integer with the first.  For example

List 1:

```
int     string
==============
1       string1
3       string2  
5       string3
```

List 2:

```
int      string
===================
1      otherstring1
2      otherstring2
3      otherstring3
4      otherstring4
5      otherstring5
```

then I want my result to be

```
int     string
===================
1      otherstring1
3      otherstring3
5      otherstring5
```

Is there a way to do this using the `IN` keyword?  Using python 3.7.

Answer (score 2):

Create a set of the integers that present in list1:

```
integers_in_list_one = {tup[0] for tup in list1}
```

Then you can do

```
common = [tup for tup in list2 if tup[0] in integers_in_list_one]
```

**Why a set?**

Since sets provide O(1) lookup, by using a set we achieve a solution with time complexity of O(n) instead of O(n^2).

Full example:

```
list_1 = [(1, 'string1'), (3, 'string2'), (5, 'string3')]
list_2 = [(1, 'otherstring1'), (2, 'otherstring2'), (3, 'otherstring3'), (4, 'otherstring4'), (5, 'otherstring5')]

integers_in_list_one = {tup[0] for tup in list_1}
common = [tup for tup in list_2 if tup[0] in integers_in_list_one]
print(common)
```

Outputs

```
[(1, 'otherstring1'), (3, 'otherstring3'), (5, 'otherstring5')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume the two lists are `list1` and `list2`. We start by extracting the integers from `list1`:

```
integers = {x for x,y in list1}
```

Here `{` and `}` are used to create a set instead of a list (because lookups are faster in a set than in a list).

Then we loop over items in `list2` and only keep strings whose number are in `integers`:

```
strings = [y for x,y in list2 if x in integers]
```

Answer (score 0):

Initial Anwser :

```
output = [a,b for a,b in list_2 if a in [a for a,b in list_1]]
```

Using set for hashing effectivity:

```
output = [a,b for a,b in list_2 if a in set([a for a,b in list_1])]
```

Comment: That's not the most readable way to write it, and the inner list is constructed ``len(list_2)`` times, which is not efficient. (Edit: even with the edited solution, problem is still present)